# uninitialized constant ApplicationController::PermittedParams strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Don't know where i'm getting wrong, i have searched a lot googling and also in SO but i don't understand what i am doing wrong.

**My Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

helper_method :clipboard, :current_user, :signed_in?, :permitted_params

def permitted_params
  @permitted_params ||= PermittedParams.new(params, current_user)       
end
```

**My Model Permitted_Param.rb**

```
class PermittedParams < Struct.new(:params, :current_user)
   %w{folder group share_link user user_file}.each do |model_name|
     define_method model_name do
       params.require(model_name.to_sym).permit(*send("#{model_name}_attributes"))
     end   
   end

   def folder_attributes
     [:name]   
   end

   def group_attributes
     [:name]   
   end

   def share_link_attributes
     [:emails, :link_expires_at, :message]   
   end

   def user_attributes
     if current_user && current_user.member_of_admins?
       [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, { :group_ids => [] }]
     else
       [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]
     end   
   end

   def user_file_attributes
     [:attachment, :attachment_file_name]   
   end 
end
```

**Log**

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-16 19:37:02 +0530
>   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT
>   "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations" Processing by
>   FoldersController#index as HTML   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".*
>   FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_admin" = ? LIMIT 1  [["is_admin", "t"]]
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admins/new Filter chain halted as
>   :require_admin_in_system rendered or redirected Completed 302 Found in
>   207ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms) Started GET "/admins/new" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2015-04-16 19:37:03 +0530 Processing by AdminsController#new as HTML
>   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
>   "users"."is_admin" = ? LIMIT 1  [["is_admin", "t"]]   Rendered
>   admins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (331.3ms)   User Load
>   (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL
>   LIMIT 1   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (21.3ms)   CACHE (0.1ms) 
>   SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
>   Rendered shared/_menu.html.erb (8.4ms)   Rendered
>   shared/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms) Completed 200 OK in 1789ms (Views:
>   1707.5ms | ActiveRecord:
>       1.7ms)
>       Started POST "/admins" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-16 19:37:19 +0530 Processing by AdminsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"5VPDMdM6Cny63T00tcgU55ukkDD9XChTQwWjAJ7IUZ0ELh6D5c7UhbpbOKdQ3atdaNIaBVk5AxctcC0j09pcvQ==",
>   "user"=>{"name"=>"ChiragArya", "email"=>"edwardmaya008@gmail.com",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
>   "commit"=>"Create admin account"}   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT 
>   "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_admin" = ? LIMIT 1 
>   [["is_admin", "t"]] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
>       NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::PermittedParams):
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:26:in `permitted_params'
>
>   app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:10:in`
>         Rendered /home/chirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (54.9ms)   Rendered
>   /home/chirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (35.3ms)   Rendered
>   /home/chirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (10.4ms)   Rendered
>   /home/chirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (227.5ms)

Comment: Where are your files placed? Share the full route. Also your Permitted_Param.rb should be called Permitted_Params.rb

Comment: @RafadeCastro, since it is Ruby, it should have been calles `permitted_params.rb` (lower case)

Comment: @RafadeCastro i instead changed to PermittedParam in controller method and worked perfectly but now after sign-up as admin i am getting another error when i'm signing in.
I have cloned this app
https://github.com/mischa78/boxroom
NoMethodError in Folders#show 
<% if permission.group.admins_group? -%>

Comment: Ok I resolved that one too Damn this code is full of errors :( after accessing admin sign in now error when i am creating new folder :/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and i resolved that after renaming my strong parameter function name to `controllername`_params

I don't know where is the mention but i'd love to know that .